# Position smart (dynamic) Admob banner to bottom of iOS screen?

Tags: ios, admob

I'm creating a smart (dynamic) Admob banner like this

```
bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait origin:CGPointMake(0,0)];
```

But how do I get it so a smart adMob banner is at the bottom of the screen? I need to know the height of the banner to be able to work out where at the bottom it's y coordinate should be, but I don't see how you do that if it's a smart (dynamically) sized banner?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out if this helps anyone

```
bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait origin:CGPointMake(0,0)];

                [bannerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,Sparrow.stage.height-bannerView.frame.size.height, bannerView.frame.size.width, bannerView.frame.size.height)];
```